# phpmyadmin limit privileges for a specific database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, privileges

I want my user to have extended privileges on all databases at the exception of one single database where the user should only have select statement right.

I have tried to limit to select only using database-specific option, but it has no effect and the user can still update the database. I suspect the extended privileges override my database-specific option.

I don't want to manage database-specific privileges for all databases as I have four users and 100+ databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exclude certain databases, AFAIK, but you *can* GRANT on a wildcard. So, if you name the one single database exception differently, say if the rest contain a prefix that that single one doesn't, you could accomplish something similar with the wildcard.

For example, if all the databases were prefixed with 'shared_' or 'common_' or something, you could GRANT all privileges for "common_%", but then control the permission of your one database without the prefix independently.

That's still involved, as you might have to rename a ton of databases, but then you only have two grants to manage, rather than one per database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to grant a MySQL user priviliges in the form of 'all except one'.
However you could use a MySQL query to generate a list of GRANT-queries like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT ALL ON ',SCHEMA_NAME,' TO user_name') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME!='exclude_database'
```

and then execute those for every user.